# Does Core Data automatically validate new values when they are set?

Tags: iphone, core-data

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992832/how-to-write-a-value-validation-method-for-core-data), someone asked how to write a validation method for Core Data. I did that, and it looks cool. But one thing doesn't happen: The validation. I can easily set any "bad" value and this method doesn't get called automatically. What's the concept behind this? Must I always first call the validation method before setting any value? So would I write setter methods which call the appropriate validation method first?

And if yes, what's the point of following a strict convention in how to write the validation method signature? I guess there's also some automatic way of validation, then. How to activate this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validation is not "automatic" especially on iOS.  On the desktop you will have the UI elements handling the call to validation.  On iOS you should be calling `validateValue:forKey:error:` with the appropriate key and dealing with the error should there be one.  The reason for this is the lack of a standard error display on iOS and the overhead of validating all values.

Note this comment in the documentation:

> If you do implement custom validation methods, you should typically not invoke them directly. Instead you should call validateValue:forKey:error: with the appropriate key. This ensures that any constraints defined in the managed object model are also applied.

Comment: Indeed I find it pretty hard work to do validation in Core Data on the iPhone. It's pretty tedious to write all that code, especially with localization. That's a case for a nice Core Data wrapper, maybe :)

Comment: I know this is an old post, but I feel it's worth adding: these methods *do* get called automatically when you try to save a managed object, and the error they set is also percolated back to the caller through the documented error-handling mechanism. Furthermore, it wouldn't make sense for CD to call validation methods when you set properties, since setters are void methods that don't take an NSError ref for a parameter. That having been said, I'll grant you that if you want to validate inputs in the GUI without saving, then it absolutely makes sense to call validateValue:forKey:error.